# php num->rows not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I keep getting an error, even though I am 100% sure I followed the example that is found in the  [PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).

The simplified version of the code can be found below.

note: connection to the database is ok.

EDIT: I keep getting an "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string" error.

EDIT: Now I keep getting "Mission Failed" even though I am sure that the row count should be 1.

Here's the coode used:

```
        @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABSE');

        $email = $db->prepare("select * from members where email = ?");
        $email->bind_param('s', $email);
        $email->execute;
        $email->store_result;
        $email->num_rows;

        if ($email > 0) {
          echo "<p>This e-mail is already in use, please try again with another e-mail.</p>";
          exit;
        } else {
          echo "mission failed";
        }

        exit;
```

EDIT:

```
        @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', 'DB');

        if ($db->connect_errno) {
          echo "<p id=\"signup_confirmed\">Error: could not connect to database. Please try again later.</p>";
          exit;
        }

        $checkRow = $db->prepare("select * from members where email = ?");
        $checkRow->bind_param('s', $email);
        $checkRow->execute;
        $checkRow->store_result;

        if ($checkRow->num_rows > 0) {
          echo "<p id=\"signup_confirmed\">This e-mail is already in use, please try again with another e-mail.</p>";
          exit;
        } else {
          echo "<p id=\"signup_confirmed\">Row checking has failed</p>";
        }
```

Comment: have you try `if ($email->num_rows() > 0) {` ?

Comment: Yes. Still not getting any results.

Comment: `$checkRow->execute;  $checkRow->store_result;`  should be `$checkRow->execute();  $checkRow->store_result();`

Comment: i recommend you to please go to the tutorial carefully http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php, you are making very silly mistakes

Comment: It finally worked. Sorry to make you upset. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

change

```
  $email->num_rows();
```

to

```
 $email->num_rows;
```

in your code

### New edit

```
$count = $email->num_rows;

        if ($count > 0) {
          echo "<p>This e-mail is already in use, please try again with another e-mail.</p>";
          exit;
        } else {
          echo "mission failed";
        }
```

### More edit

change this to

```
$email = $db->prepare("select * from members where email = ?");
$email->bind_param('s', $email);
```

this

```
 //  you are over riding your  $email value with the query thats the reason its not working 
$query= $db->prepare("select * from members where email = ?");
$query->bind_param('s', $email);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It kept me busy for a whole day... But why is it that the brackets should be left away?

Comment: there are two ways of calling num_rows in object oriented approach you dont need to pass the additional argument required. its just the way it is used and its much simpler this way.... anyways it is confusing in the start.. if my answer was helpful mark it as verified so others will be able to find it useful

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't show any results anymore... I updated the question details.

Comment: Still keep getting "mission failed". Maybe because I haven't closed the connection or something?

Comment: you're onto something. I checked if the "->execute" was successful. It wasn't... Connection to the database is successful though. It seems it is either the prepare, bind or execute code.

Comment: updated the answer see it, you are over riding your email address value with your query, how it will bind a query with itself this is the error, see a reference here - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: I have updated the question. Too bad the overriding isn't the cause. I still get a failure.

Answer (score 0):

`$email` is a result set, an object.

It will hold data returned from SQL operation.

You need to get the `num_rows()` in a variable.

Corrected code:

```
$cnt = $email->num_rows;
if ($cnt > 0) {
```

OR

```
if ($email->num_rows > 0) {
```

Comment: Hey Pupil, turns out that I should have left the brackets out.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'USER', 'PASSWORD?', 'DATABSE');

    $query_email = "select * from members where email = ?";
    $email = $db->prepare($query_email);
    $email->bind_param('s', $email);
    $email->execute();
    $email->store_result();

    if ( $email->num_rows > 0) {
      echo "<p id=\"signup_confirmed\">This e-mail is already in use, please try again with another e-mail.</p>";
      exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
    `if ($email > 0)` use `if ($email->num_rows() > 0)`